Equivalence between discrete and continuous kalman filter. What is the correct equivalence between a continuous white noise and a discrete one?
I'm working in to prove the equivalence of the continuous and discrete Kalman Filter. But I had a different result. Can someone help me?
From my research in literature I got that the equivalence is obtained if we use the following result:
A continuous-time white noise with spectral density Qc can be approximated by a discrete-time white noise with covariance Qd using the condition (1) below
\begin{equation}
Qd = Qc.Ts          
\end{equation}
All deduction of the continuous Kalman filter is based on this relation. In order to verify this, one can see:
Brown - Introduction to Random Signals and Applied Kalman Filtering with Matlab Exercises 4th Edition - Page 371
or
Simon - Optimal State Estimation - Page 230
In order to check this relation I am using the MATLAB function covar which gives the output and state covariance of system driven by white noise. The function works for continuous and discrete systems
https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dynamicsystem.covar.html
Notice that I could test it by means of others functions, as for example lqe or kalman. However, the covar function is enough to get the point.
I've tested the relation (1) with the following code:
clear
close all
clc

% Sistem

A = [-10 -20;35 -50];
B = [1; 1;];
C = [1 0];
D = 0;

fs = 2000;
Ts = 1/fs;

sys = ss(A,B,C,D);

sysd = c2d(sys,Ts);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Relation  from literature:

Qc = 600
Qd = Qc*Ts

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

[Pc,Qcc] = covar(sys,Qc)
[Pd,Qdd] = covar(sysd,Qd)

The results are:
Pc =
8.7500
Qcc = [8.7500   10.6250; 10.6250   13.4375]
Pd =
2.1874e-06
Qdd = 1.0e-05 * [0.2187    0.2656;  0.2656    0.3359]
Clearly the condition (1) not leads to an equivalence. It was expected Qcc = Qdd and Pc = Pd.
After some tests I see that using the relation (2):
\begin{equation}
Qd = Qc/Ts   
\end{equation}
I got the equivalence that I want. The result in MATLAB is
Pc = 8.7500
Qcc = [8.7500   10.6250; 10.6250   13.4375]
Pd =     8.7498
Qdd = [8.7498   10.6248; 10.6248   13.4374]
Which are clearly equivalent!
So, I would like some help to interpretate this result. I see that the deduction from the books seems to be correct, however the results from MATLAB does not agree with it.
I made a longer test using lqe function to get a Kalman filter and the results also confirms equivalence with condition the relation (2).
Have been researching in a lot of papers and books but don't find yet a reasonable answer.

Matlab's c2d function uses essentially the same process as (8.20) from Simon's book*.
When you generate your sysd and then test it with covar, the value you plug into covar is acting like the measurement noise, not the process noise.
If you look on page 232 of Simon's book, (8.15) will tell you that the conversion of the measurement noise is $$R_d = \frac {R_c}{T_s}$$
So there's your discrepancy.
If you really want to do this experimentally instead of working out the math, you need to set up your continuous-time system as
sys = ss(A, eye(A), eye(A), 0)

This describes a system that acts like (8.1) in Simon's book.
I think this will give you the results you expect for $Q$.  Note that Matlab may not be nice about taking a scalar input for the covariance in covar -- you may need to give it your scalar times an identity matrix.

* Actually, it uses an algorithm that works just fine if $A \Delta t$ is singular -- but I digress.
